# Json schema change property type based on parent property

Tags: jsonschema

I have to write a condition, if `kind` column equal `OPTIONAL`, then change `uuid` type to `[null, "string"]`. I have json schema like(most of the fields are hidden, except for those necessary to fulfill the condition):

```
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "kind": { "type": "string" },
              "bucket": {
                "items": {
                  "anyOf": [
                    {
                      "properties": {
                        "properties": {
                          "properties": {
                            "uuid": { "type": "string" }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
```

I don't have experience with  json schema, could you please show exact place, where I should put the condition. thanks

Answer (score 0):

solution was after properties add if then else statement with whole struture

```
        "if": {
          "properties": {
            "kind": { "enum": ["OPTIONAL"] }
          }
        },
        "then": {
          "properties": {
            "bucket": {
              "items": {
                "properties": {
                  "properties": {
                    "properties": {
                      "uuid": {
                        "type": ["string", "null"]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "else": {
          "properties": {
            "backet": {
              "items": {
                "properties": {
                  "properties": {
                    "properties": {
                      "uuid": {
                        "type": "string",
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
```